# python dictionary manipulation not working

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I am doing data processing to filter and sort and etc...

```
for stock in context.timeSeriesData:
    try:
        if context.timeSeriesData.iloc[1,:][stock][2] > 0 and context.timeSeriesData.iloc[0,:][stock][2] > 0:
            if context.timeSeriesData.iloc[1,:][stock][2] > context.timeSeriesData.iloc[0,:][stock][2]:
                context.tradingList[stock] = []       
                increment = context.timeSeriesData.iloc[1,:][stock][2] / context.timeSeriesData.iloc[0,:][stock][2]
                context.tradingList[stock].append(increment)            
    except:
        pass      

try:
    sorted_tradingList = sorted(context.tradingList.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
except:
    pass



try:
    sorted_tradingList.clear()
except:
    pass



for x,stock in sorted_tradingList:
    if len(context.tradingBook) < (1.25/context.weightLong):
        if stock in data and 'price' in data[stock]:
            context.tradingBook[stock] = [] 
            context.tradingBook[stock].append(0.0)
            order_target_percent(stock, context.weightLong) 




for k, v in context.tradingBook.iteritems():
    v[0] +=1

timeToSell = {k:v for (k,v) in context.tradingBook.iteritems() if v[0] == 10}

for stock in timeToSell:
    if stock in data and 'price' in data[stock]:
        TargetHedge = (len(context.tradingBook) - 1) * context.weightShort
        order_target_percent(stock, 0.0) 
        del context.tradingBook[stock]

if len(timeToSell)>0:
    timeToSell.clear()

TargetHedge = (len(context.tradingBook)) * context.weightShort
order_target_percent(sid(8554), TargetHedge)
```

In the first loop context.timeSeriesData will generate many sets of company with three data elements.  For example, the first two is shown below.  Lets look at AAPL, 311 is an industry code (which I don't care to use it now), the second element 18024000000 is net income, and 3.08 is the earning per share (which I want to manipulate)

```
DataFrame:
          Equity(24 [AAPL])         
1  [311.0, 18024000000.0, 3.08] 
2  [311.0, 18024000000.0, 3.08]
```

In the data above first line indicates data received prior day and the second line indicates the data just arrived.  So in the future if the DataFrame: changes to as shown below. The the computer should put that into context.tradingBook

```
DataFrame:
          Equity(24 [AAPL])         
1  [311.0, 18024000000.0, 3.08] 
2  [311.0, 19033000000.0, 3.79]
```

so the purpose is that when a new data is received, and the earning per share improves it will be stored into context.tradingList.  Then it shorts by the highest "increment"

```
sorted_tradingList = sorted(context.tradingList.items(), key = lambda x: x[1], reverse = True)
```

Then the code

```
for k, v in context.tradingBook.iteritems():
    v[0] +=1
```

will add one day each time this whole block of code is processed (once a day).  As you can see it starts with 0 day, context.tradingBook[stock].append(0.0), but each day it will add one day until 10 days have passed, at which point, I will try to sell them.

order_target_percent(stock, context.weightLong) is a code to buy or sell stocks which is unique to my system so don't worry about it.  My question is...  why it is not adding days.  I am having issue with

```
for k, v in context.tradingBook.iteritems():
    v[0] +=1
```

It is currently not adding days.  What am I doing wrong.  Also I have another question, if you are interested in following along this far.  But I will let you know once we get the first step down.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Your  bare except is not a good idea, you should catch specific errors or at least  print/log any execpetions

Comment: I know.  But when I run through the debug mode, nothing appears malfunctioning.

Comment: @UjaeKang exceptions, by definition, are things that don't happen normally.

Comment: But codes do work as expected when I run through the debug mode.  Problem happens when it gets to the     [for k, v in context.tradingBook.iteritems():
        v[0] +=1]   line

Comment: @UjaeKang, what is the problem that happens when you have don't catch any exceptions?

Comment: Padraic,  I updated the code and I am realizing that your were right, it is not processing [sorted_tradingList.clear()]  error message is [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'clear'].  I wasn't aware of it, because of no exception comment.

Comment: Yes, lists don't have a clear method, if you want to delete the list use `del sorted_tradingList`, if you want to create an empty list use `sorted_tradingList = []`, but if you do that then your next loop will have nothing to iterate over as `sorted_tradingList` will be empty

Comment: Padraic, would you please offer me a solution, how I should do to clean out the data element of dictionary so that it would be back to empty set like when I first declared it?  [context.tradingList = {}]

Comment: If you want to change a value in the dict to an empty set use `your_dict[key] = set()`, once you  don't have any other references to objects, when you rebind a name in python `my_whatever = whatever` the old data will be gc'd.  Not sure if you mean dict or set as `{}` would create a dictionary, you need `set()` when creating an empty set

Comment: Anyway, since you don't handle the exceptions you'd better not catch them. For example the second `try`-`catch` if catched you will end up without `sorted_tradingList` defined which means that subsequent code couldn't succeed anyway.

Comment: I think I got to the problem.  I am a bit slow.  I will give you an update.  That was where the problem was anyways...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was at

```
try:
    sorted_tradingList.clear()
except:
    pass
```

It was not working and I wasn't aware of it.

Comment: lesson: remove all bare `except`